# Dictionary extension method for specfic value type? e.g. Dictionary<T, List<U>>

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to write an extension method that works only with dictionaries that have a List as value?

I want to write one that checks if the key is existent, it will add another entry to the list. And if the key is not existent a new list is initialized, the entry added, and then everything added to the dictionary.

Now I am not sure what the method head looks like or if it is even possible to limit the function to a specific value type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course. In the extension method defintition you use `List<T>`, which the `T` defined in the type arguments. In this case named `TListValue` to avoid ambiguity:

```
public static void DoSomething<TKey, TListValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, List<TListValue>> dictionary)
{
    ...
}
```

You can use it without specifying the type parameters. They should be infered:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> u = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
u.DoSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample implementation of the method that you want to write:

```
static class DictExtensions {
    public static void Insert<TKey,TVal>(this IDictionary<TKey,List<TVal>> d, TKey k, TVal v) {
        List<TVal> current;
        if (!d.TryGetValue(k, out current)) {
            d.Add(k, new List<TVal> { v } );
        } else {
            current.Add(v);
        }
    }
}
```

The name `Add` would collide with the instance method of `Dictionary`, so I used the name `Insert`.

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/UNUWtz)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than an extension method, I would personally create a class inheriting from Dictionary:

```
public class ListDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>>
{
    new public List<TValue> this[TKey index]
    {
        get
        {
            List<TValue> list = null;
            if (!TryGetValue(index, out list))
            {
                list = new List<TValue>();
                Add(index, list);
            }
            return list;
        }
        set
        {
            if (ContainsKey(index))
                base[index] = value;
            else
                Add(index, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
ListDictionary<string, string> dictionary = new ListDictionary<string, string>();

dictionary["list1"].Add("item1"); // list will be initialised here
dictionary["list1"].Add("item2");
dictionary["list2"].Add("item1"); // and another
```